# Save object modifications in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on iOS app in Swift.

Assuming I have the following object stored in CoreData:

```
class Exercise: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var sets: Int16
    @NSManaged var reps: Int16
}
```

How do I save all the history of changes to name, sets and reps made by user?

User is allowed to change any of attributes as many times as he wants and I need to keep track of it to show progress, etc.

Do I need to create an object-duplicate (with the same id?) on each change or there's a better solution for keeping revisions?

Comment: I would create a "to many" relationship to another object that stored the history with fields for, say, date of change, item that changed and old/new value.

Comment: Why didn't I think about it? :) Please add it as answer. It's a simple solution and way better than creating duplicates. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a 'to-many' relationship to a history entity.  The history entity will store the date of the change, the field that was changed and old/new values -

```
class Exercise: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var sets: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var reps: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var history: NSSet

}


class ExerciseHistory: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var changeDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var changedItem: String
    @NSManaged var newValue: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var oldValue: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var exercise: Exercise

}
```